# Json returns characters

Tags: php, javascript, json

When I am trying to echo json in php it returns  **\n \r \t** . How I can remove them?

Here is my code:

```
            ob_start();
                $this->load->view('competition/template',$q);
                $content = ob_get_clean();
                $data['content'] = $content;

             echo json_encode($data);
```

And am getting:

```
</table>{"ok":1,"content":"<table>\r\n   <tr>\r\n\t    <td>Competitor name<\/td>\r\n\t    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"competitor_name[2]\" \/><\/td>\r\n   <\/tr>\r\n   <tr>\r\n   <\/tr>\r\n   <tr>\r\n   <\/tr>\r\n   <tr>\r\n   <\/tr>\r\n<\/table>"}
```

This is the template.php file:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->__('Competitor name');?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="competitor_name[<?php echo $id?>]" /></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

After str_replace or preg_repalce, am getting:

```
{"ok":1,"content":"<table>   <tr>    <td>Competitor name<\/td>    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"competitor_name[1]\" \/><\/td>   <\/tr> <\/table>"}
```

Now my problem is  **\.**

Thank you.

Ok I found the anwser. Here it is:

```
 $content = preg_replace("@[\\r|\\n|\\t|\\/|\\\"]+@", "", $content);
```

But am not sure why I was getting this problem .

Comment: do you want to remove them or replace them with valid HTML (`<br>`) ?

Comment: Sounds like they come from the template... you *could* just str_replace them out I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove un-necessary whitespace from your content using:

```
$content = preg_replace("@[\\r|\\n|\\t]+@", "", $content);
$data['content'] = $content;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data['content'] = str_replace( array("\n","\t","\r"), "", $content );
```

Comment: you will need to escape twice ie `\\n`

Comment: oh I thought he was just showing where those chars are not that that is actually the output :D

Comment: What i mean is you need to specify your array as `array("\\n","\\t","\\r")` so it finds the characters

Comment: what I meant is that the output actually contained new line and tab characters rather than \n and \t (as strings)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the new lines and tabs from the `$content` before you add it to `$data` and `json_encode` it.